# Delete action is not working in laravel?

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5, delete-row

I have a form which has the delete button in it.

```
 <form method="post" id="delform" action="{{ url('/templates/delete',[$template->template_id]) }}">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
  {{ csrf_field() }}

 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="del" value="delete>

  </form>
```

then in my routes web.php:

```
Route::delete('/templates/delete/{id}','TemplateController@delete');
```

when i click on delete i get this error:

[image]

what am i doing wong please help? thanks in advance

I have added my composer.json here:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"        "rmccue/requests": ">=1.0"    },
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
}
}
```

here is the console logs:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot double-quotes to close value from input submit

```
<input type="submit" ... value="delete">
```

and a comma in composer json after package:

```
"maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
```

Finally HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE actions. So, when defining PUT, PATCH or  DELETE routes that are called from an HTML form, you will need to add a hidden _method field to the form. The value sent with the _method field will be used as the HTTP request method.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
```

You may use the method_field helper to generate the _method input:

```
{{ method_field('DELETE') }}
```

[Laravel routes documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Look at [rest conventions](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html)

Comment: thx for the reply as you can i do have the hidden field in my fom

Comment: @Mikethetechy try run `composer dumpautoload -o` and test again

Comment: when i run composer dumpautoload -o i get this error [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
  "./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON
  Parse error on line 11:
  ...l": "~2.1.0"        "rmccue/requests": "
  ----------------------^
  Expected one of: 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']'

Comment: please see the edited question added my composer.json

Comment: Your json have too much errors... I will solve to you... wait!

Comment: i think its this line: "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"        "rmccue/requests": ">=1.0"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139441/discussion-between-thiago-franca-and-mikethetechy).